# Sublime Text HTML Block Comment Containing Comments

Tags: html, sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimetext3

Is there a plugin to help with HTML commenting a block of code that may already contain other comments?

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container"></div>
  <!-- /.container -->
</div>
<!-- /.wrapper -->
```

BBEdit has a built in feature where if you select all of this code and apply a block comment, it will change the existing comments temporarily so that the main block comment can be applied. The output in the editor would look like:

```
<!-- 
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="container"></div>
      <!~~ /.container ~~>
    </div>
    <!~~ /.wrapper ~~>
 -->
```

Uncommenting the block would set the ~ characters back to dashes - so the individual comments would still be in place.

I am not looking for this specific functionality, but something that allows for block commenting content that already contains HTML comments without having to manually remove/edit the existing comments.

Comment: great question - would love to see a simple plugin for this.

Comment: I have the feeling that this would fit better on SuperUser.com

Answer (score 1):

I could not find a plugin that does this, so I wrote one.

Installation instructions are available at https://github.com/philsinatra/HTMLNestedComments